# Callback from C function vs from C++ method

Tags: c++, callback

I have Foo class with a bar() method.
I also have a bar2() function (outside of any class)
And a Xpto class where I need to set the constructor with some callback.

```
class Foo
{
  //...
  public:
     bar()
     {
       //do stuff..
     }
  //...
}

//isolated C function outside class
void bar2()
{
}

class Xpto
{
  //...
  public:
     Xpto(std::function<void()> &callback)
     {
       //do stuff..
     }
  //...
}

int main()
{
   Xpto x1(bar2); // <---- compiles

   Foo myFoo;
   Xpto x2(myFoo.bar); // <--- doesn't compile

   return 0;
}
```

**Why can I create the Xpto object using a callback method from Foo object?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `myFoo.bar` has signature not equal to `std::function<void()>` (since it's member function). You can use `std::bind` (and look at right syntax of using member function pointer).

```
Xpto x2(std::bind(&Foo::bar, std::ref(myFoo)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want use method you should use a signature for it, as:

```
class Xpto
{
  //...
  public:
     template <class T>
     Xpto(void (T::* func)())
     {
       //do stuff..
     }

     Xpto(std::function<void()> &callback)
     {
       //do stuff..
     }
  //...
}
```

This line `void (T::* func)()` say that you will accept a method that return void and receives no argument from a objetc T as argument.

And use like that:

```
Xpto x2(&myFoo::bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using implicit conversion for `Xpto x1(bar2);`. It is calling the implicit constructor of `std::function<void()>` to create one from `bar2`.

On the second case, you are giving a member function which has not a signature of `void()`. If instead is `void Foo:*()` (pointer to member function).

To work, you have to use [`std::bind`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/) like so :

```
Xpto x2(std::bind(&Foo::bar, myFoo));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `myFoo.bar`, without the `()`s, is not actually a legal C++ expression (though such a thing would be perfectly meaningful in, say, python), whereas `bar2` is just a pointer to a nullary free function returning `void`, which would be convertible to `std::function<void()>`.

The correct way to refer to a member function would be `&Foo::bar`, and then you additionally would need to provide an instance of `Foo`. You could do one of:

```
Xpto x2(std::bind(&Foo::bar, myFoo));
Xpto x2([myFoo]{ myFoo.bar(); });
```

Note also that typically you *don't* want to take arguemnts by `std::function<Sig>`. Prefer to write your constructor as:

```
template <typename F>
Xpto(F func) {
    // if you really need a std::function, create it here
}
```